# Anti-flag transitive affine planes

Tags: projective-geometry, automorphism-groups, affine-geometry, incidence-geometry

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an axiomatic affine plane. First let $\mathcal{A}$ be finite.

Suppose that the automorphism group of $\mathcal{A}$ acts transitively on nonincident point-line pairs (that is, on the *anti-flags*).

Are such planes classified ? Are there examples known besides Desarguesian affine planes ?

Is anything even known when the affine planes are *not* finite ?

Comment: It seems that such affine plane are just affine subplanes of Moufang projective planes.